# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pgeocode'

Tags: python

I've installed pgeocode in my PyCharm project folder, through PyCharm, as I have done for other modules but for some reasons it's saying the module is not found.

I also tried installing pgeocode from the command line so it's accesible across all projects but no change

```
import pgeocode

dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('GB')
distance = dist.query_postal_code('Postcode1', 'Postcode2')
print(distance)
```

Looking in my installed PyCharm modules I can see pgeocode there:

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `pip --version`?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall first using :

```
pip uninstall pgeocode
```

Then re-install using :

```
pip install pgeocode
```

Comment: I tried this both in the command line and then in PyCharm but no change